# Set Up and run WordCount Hadoop 1.2.1 on Eclipse

Tags: hadoop, word-count

I setup Hadoop 1.2.1 single Node. and I want to Run WordCount of Hadoop 1.2.1 Example on Eclipse Mars,can you guide me about this,and tell me how can I do this step by step ?thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Java Maven project, and include all the required jars (i.e., your current version of hadoop) for MapReduce Jars in the POM.xml file
2. Maven build your application.
3. Create a Java classes which extends Mapper & Reducer classes, and define the Job configurations in Main method.
4. Save this as Jar and run in the terminal, this will run in Cluster as well as Pseudo mode.
5. If you want to run it using Eclipse, run it from eclipse, It will run in eclipse in pseudo mode.

***for refernce*** please find the below link to configure the Input output paths in the Mapreduce programming, creation of Maven project.

https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/25/setup-maven-project-for-hadoop-in-5mn/

**Note:** Set the Hadoop path in the Path, I hope you already configured the same while Installation.

Alternatively, you can also create a project by copying all the Hadoop jars (i.e., hadoop-core, log4j etc.) without Maven build, but this is not a best practice.